# PostgreSQL versioning question

Tags: postgresql

In my terminal, a CLI query tells me my PostgreSQL is currently 13.2. I am using MacOS and have likely also used Homebrew to take care of installs and updates. I check things out with the brew command and I am confused. Specifically:

```
brew info postgres
postgresql: stable 14.1 (bottled), HEAD
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.2_1 (3,218 files, 42.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-04-21 at 16:54:25
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/postgresql.rb
License: PostgreSQL
```

So I see 14.1 as a version and yet the working system is 13.2

I just want to update to 13.5 for now, but I am confused about why my brew info is telling me all about 14.1? What is likely going on here and what steps can I take to update my PostgreSQL without blowing everything up?

Comment: How did you determine the version? `select version()` or `psql -v`

Comment: I used psql -v, which matches the directory stated above.

Comment: That reports the version of the `psql` tool. It's not the version of the database server. It seems your server is at 14.1 but your client tools are at 13.2

Comment: Umm. nope. 

select version();
                                                      version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29), 64-bit

Comment: I wouldn't know a mac from dalek, but I would assume that that is telling you that 14.1 is the latest available, but 13.2 is actually installed.

Comment: Ok.. I suppose that makes some sense.
Ha. This all came about because I tried updating to 13.5.
 brew postgresql-upgrade-database
==> brew install postgresql@13
Error: postgresql@13: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source postgresql@13
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
Error: No postgresql 13.* version installed!